# AsyncTask: doInBackground is not finishing

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'am trying to implement an AsyncTask in Android that will load all my data from the database. Therefore I used the `onPreExecute` method to start a `ProgressDialog`

```
public class DataLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private LoginActivity activity;
private ProgressDialog nDialog;

public DataLoader (LoginActivity act){
    this.activity = act;
    nDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    System.out.print("Start AsyncTask");
    nDialog.setMessage("Loading data..");
    nDialog.setTitle("Starting the application");
    nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    nDialog.setCancelable(true);
    nDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {
    System.out.println("Starting doInBackground");
    loadDashboardData();
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    nDialog.dismiss();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(activity.getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

The I use the `doInBackground` method to load call a function to load the data. This method is called from an visible activity. The task is called with:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DataLoader dl = new DataLoader(this);
        dl.execute();
    }
}
```

And the code for the `doInBackground` is:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {
    System.out.println("Starting doInBackground");
    loadDashboardData();
    return null;
}
```

Now the problem is that my `doInBackground` method will not finish. I tried to implement the `loadDashboardData()` call in the `onPreExecute` method. This will not show my dialog box but it will load the data correctly. In this case the UI Thread is not responding and will response after all the data has been loaded.

What can hinder the `doInBackground` method to execute correctly and load the data properly? The called method works (because I can call it and get the correct data). Also I'am not seeing the `println` in my run console.
In the frontend I can see the progressbar spinning, but in the backend I can see that no data is loaded.

Comment: How do you execute the Asynctask? Please show your code.

Comment: @DmitriBorohhov I added more code. Does this help you? Or do you mean something else with "execute" than `dl.execute()`?

Comment: where is loadDashboardData()? There might be some problem in that.

Comment: Why are you returning `null` from a `void` method? remove the `return null;` statement

Comment: I get  an errormessage that I have to add a return statement. Also if I change from `Void` to `void` I get an errormessage that I return an invalid type. - As far as I unterstand this has something to do with the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Would you post the code of loadDashboardData() ?

Comment: Your Asynctask structure is fine, I can get it to run if I leave only the System.out calls. What you are doing in loadDashboardData() is something only you know, perhaps you need to troubleshoot that method separately. One more questionable thing for me is why you need to override the constructor, instead you could just pass your activity as an argument to doInBackground() or to onPostExecute()

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute()` You are not overriding onPostExcute(). That function will never be called. It should be more like `@Override protected void onPostExecute(Void)`. But why <Void,Void,Void> ? Make it <String,String,String> and use the parameters to foreward messages and display errors and so.

Comment: @DmitriBorohhov The error was actually inside my custom method. I tried to call another AsyncTask and this would lead to an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are overriding the wrong method name : )
It should be

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // your code
}
```

as in your case the variable which `doInBackground` return is `Void`.

You can check the documentation about [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

Comment: Thanks for that hint. This was one problem in my code.

Comment: Is that fixed your issue? : )